# RecyclerView используя GridLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Делаю вывод `ImageView`, но картинка сильно растягивается по высоте. в `xml` естественно стоит `wrap_content`. Кто сталкивался с таким? Если надо какие-то куски кода - сброшу.

Разметка элемента:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"> 

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgMovies"/> 

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Размеры картинок и размеры элементов для их отображения могут быть разными на разных устройствах и разных ориентациях экрана.

Засим надо программно назначать размеры для `ImageView` в соответствии с размером экрана, и размером изображения.

```
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsImg = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) YOURS_IMAGE_VIEW.getLayoutParams();

            int widthDevice = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            float width = widthDevice;

            int numOfColsInGridLayoutManager = ЧИСЛО_КОЛОНОК;
            width /= (float) numOfColsInGridLayoutManager;

            float scale = width / ШИРИНА_ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ_В_ПИКСЕЛЯХ;
            float height = (scale) * ВЫСОТА_ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ_В_ПИКСЕЛЯХ;

            paramsImg.width = (int) width;
            paramsImg.height = (int) height;

            YOURS_IMAGE_VIEW.setLayoutParams(paramsImg);
```

Таким образом вы получите `ImageView` с высотой, пропорциональной высоте картинке при заданной ширине.

Не забудьте проставить для `ImageView` `android:scaleType="fitXY"`